# How to create a 1280x800 screenshot of a Chrome Browser viewport

Tags: google-chrome, screenshot

The [Chrome Webstore](http://chrome.google.com/webstore) requires screenshots of the exact size 1280x800.

Using the system-built-in screenshotter, I have often failed by a few pixels, which required tedious  image cropping by hand or the `convert` tool.

How are those easily created?

Comment: If you want to reopen and have updates, see the conversation around https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40837200#40837200.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The old answer no longer works for `chrome-extension://` pages. On systems that support it like Ubuntu, you can [use the *Shutter* app.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262253/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-with-dimensions) On OS X, [the shutter project mentions](https://github.com/Gizra/KnowledgeBase/wiki/Shutter:-useful-screenshot-utility,-similar-to-OSX-Skitch) the [skitch app](http://evernote.com/skitch/).

---

<strike>An easy way to do this is install [Window Resizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh) and [Fireshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/take-webpage-screenshots/mcbpblocgmgfnpjjppndjkmgjaogfceg).</strike>

Comment: Would the anonymous downvoter care to explain, or not?

Answer (score -1):

With Firefox, this is *real easy*:

```
Menu -> Developer -> Responsive Design Mode (Ctrl-Shift-M)
```

gives you a drop-down to select the window size. There is also a button to create a Screenshot at this exact size.

[image: responsive design of this page set to 1920x1080]